# Install pattern on Sandbox Genexus Server

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

Is it possible to add/install pattern on Sandbox Genexus Server? We're trying to commit our application on sandbox along with the WW+ pattern. If yes, how to do that and if there's any payment needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add/install third party patterns (or components of any type) on Sandbox Server.